# How to add a pause button into a Jquery image slider?

Tags: jquery

I'm making an image slider for a site I'm building for my college course and I'm having trouble getting it to work.
I'm pretty new to using JQuery so please keep it simple.

I've found some code with will allow images to slide which is looped. I'm wanting to add a pause button to it but my efforts have failed so far. 
This is what I have so far.

```
    var pause = 'inactive';

if (pause === 'inactive'){
    setInterval(function() {
    var nextItem = $('.image.active').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active').next('.image');

    if (nextItem.length === 0) {
        nextItem = $('.image').first();
    }

    nextItem.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active ');
    }, 3500);
}


$('#pause').click(function(){
    pause = 'active' 
});
```

The looping works, but the pause button doesn't.
All help is appreciated. Also sorry if its a simple mistake I've over looked.
P.S. Using the latest version of JQuery (2.0.3)

Comment: You probably want to look into `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var pause = 'inactive';
setInterval(function() {
    if (pause == 'inactive'){
        var nextItem = $('.image.active').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active').next('.image');
        if (nextItem.length === 0) {
            nextItem = $('.image').first();
        }
        nextItem.fadeIn(1000).addClass('active ');
    }
}, 3500);            
$('#pause').click(function(){
    pause = 'active' 
});
```